# Power BI query to return same-name list results from multiple subsites

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

We have a SharePoint site that users will create item records as a new subsite with a template.  On this template is a list, we'll call List A.  There are 90+ of these subsites with the same 'List A' name.

On List A there is a "Status" field with the "Closed" choice.  I am looking to make a report (preferably in Table/Excel form) that will query all the 'List A' lists that have a Status field set to 'Closed'.

I am looking at OData queries but I'm very new to Power BI.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would build a query based on one subsite example, using the built-in connector for a **SharePoint Online List**.  I would apply the Status = Closed filter. Then I would replace the hard-coded Site with a Query Parameter.

Now you can right-click that Query and choose Create Function.

Next you need a Query that lists your 90+ subsites with their URL.  There might be an OData query that can do this or you might need to maintain a manual list e.g. in Excel.  Then you can add a Custom column that calls the Query Function (created above) and passes each subsite URL.

Expand that table-type Custom column and the result will be the filtered rows from all the subsites.